# Combined `mkdir` and `cd`?

Tags: bash, cd-command, mkdir

is there any way (what is the easiest way in bash) to combine the following:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
```

The manpage for `mkdir` does not describe anything like that, maybe there is a fancy version of `mkdir`? I know that `cd` has to be shell builtin, so the same would be true for the fancy `mkdir`...

Aliasing?

Comment: You can't alias two commands together directly.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Function?

```
mkcdir ()
{
    mkdir -p -- "$1" &&
       cd -P -- "$1"
}
```

Put the above code in the `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc` or another file sourced by your shell. Then source it by running e.g. `source ~/.bashrc` to apply changes.

After that simply run `mkcdir foo` or `mkcdir "nested/path/in quotes"`.

Notes:

- `"$1"` is the first argument of the `mkcdir` command. Quotes around it protects the argument if it has spaces or other special characters.
- `--` makes sure the passed name for the new directory is not interpreted as an option to `mkdir` or `cd`, giving the opportunity to create a directory that starts with `-` or `--`.
- `-p` used on `mkdir` makes it create extra directories if they do not exist yet, and `-P` used makes `cd` resolve symbolic links.
- Instead of `source`-ing the rc, you may also restart the terminal emulator/shell.

Comment: quotes around `"$1"` will protect the argument if it has spaces.

Comment: and put this in .bashrc?

Comment: exactly ;) ... no big deal

Comment: @glenn jackman: thanks for the `"$1"`

Comment: What's the purpose of `--`?

Comment: @Zaz `-- ` is used to make sure that the following parameters are not parsed as a options to modify the behaviour of the command. In this case it makes sure the passed name for the new directory is not interpreted as an option to mkdir or cd, giving the option to create a directory that starts with - or -- .

Comment: In case someone's wondering, the `-P` used makes cd resolve symbol links. The `-p` used on mkdir makes it create extra directories if they do not exists yet.

Comment: I normally use $ mkdir gulp && cd gulp in my arch linux

Comment: In case someone is wondering: You need to put the function in .bashrc and then add a line `export <name_of_my_function>. Then `source ~/.bashrc` or restart terminal, and the function will be available as a command. I really think the comments should be integrated into the answer, but I don't want to intrude to someone else's answer.

Comment: I am calling it `mc`!

Comment: Do we need an `|| exit` following the cd?

 e.g. `mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -P -- "$1" || exit`

Comment: "exit" would mean "logout" : I am sure you do not want that ^^

Comment: when using oh-my-zsh there is a function `take` defined, so you can use something like `take somenewdir` . The function looks like this: `take () { mkdir -p $@ && cd ${@:$#} }`

Answer (score 389):

I think creating a function is the most appropriate way to do this, but just for listing all alternative ways, you could write:

```
mkdir foo && cd "$_"
```

`$_`is a special parameter that holds the last argument of the previous command. The quote around `$_` make sure it works even if the folder name contains spaces.

### Why use double quotes?

In some shells, such as `zsh`, the double quotes surrounding the `$_` are not necessary even when the directory name contains spaces. They are required for this command to work in `bash`, however.

For example, running this command in bash 3.2.57 on macOS 10.13.6:

```bsh
mkdir "my directory" && cd $_
```

results in this output:

```bsh
bash: cd: my: No such file or directory
```

However, if we surround `$_` with double quotes, the command returns successfully.

```bsh
bash-3.2$ mkdir "my directory" && cd "$_"
bash-3.2$ echo $?
0
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Same line version of `$!`, in this case, is `!#:1`.  i.e. `"$_"` can be replaced with `!#:1`.

Comment: Strange, but this answer doesn't work for me. It works when I start `bash --norc`, but when config is active then `echo $_` echoes `$_`, while `echo ${_}` works. I couldn't find the reason.
Probably `${_}` is more safe variation and should be used in the answer?

Comment: Also, without `--norc`, this command `echo abc; echo def; echo $_` echoes `abc  def  $_` (each on new line). When using `--norc`, the same command yields `abc  def  def` (each on new line).

Comment: @MarSoft Weird! I wonder if it's a difference in the version of `bash`? It works for me under `bash 4.3.46` whether if I supply `--norc` or not. I would be curious to see what your `bashrc` looks like if it works when starting the shell without config, even though I don't think you can modify special parameters like `_`.

Comment: @Zajn, I found that the culprit is a [`git-prompt`](http://volnitsky.com/project/git-prompt/) script. Yet to determine how does it achieve such behaviour :) Probably any `PROMPT_COMMAND` will influence the `$_`?

Comment: @nyxee `$_`'s value will be `foo` in this example. If I had instead typed `mkdir workspace`, the value of `$_` would have been `workspace`, and `cd "$_"` would change our current directory to the newly created `workspace`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Does not work inside of shell & works perfectly at command prompt.

Comment: why did you add the double quotation ? I just tried and It works without it. Also, it makes it look really ugly and might discourage some people

Comment: @Suhaib Without the double quotes, this command will not work correctly using `bash`. I've tried it in `zsh` and confirmed that it works without the double quotes, but since the question was tagged with `bash`, I answered accordingly.

Comment: @Suhaib As explained in the answer, the double quotes ensure that the command works if the directory name contains spaces. Try running `mkdir "test folder" && cd $_` in `bash` and see the result. I should have specified in my last comment that this pertains to directories with spaces in their names.

Comment: @SHiON Adding double-quotes is necessary in `bash` when creating a directory that contains spaces. Since the question is tagged for `bash`, I answered accordingly.

Comment: I find it humorous that the best answer here is one that ends with an error: `bash: cd: my: No such file or directory`.  I mean, it shows that the `cd` is being invoked and `my` is the argument but `pwd && mkdir thisdir && cd $_ && pwd` demonstrates the point without an error.  All the same, TIL about the `$_` command.  Thanks!

Comment: @harperville The reason for the error at the end of the answer is to demonstrate the need for quotes surrounding `$_` in certain shells, namely `bash`. Perhaps I should re-word that section to more clearly state that without the `"$_"`, that is the error you will see.

Answer (score 26):

Bash (using word designators):

```
/tmp/bug$ mkdir "some dir"
/tmp/bug$ cd !$
cd "some dir"
/tmp/bug/some dir$
```

`!$` expands to the last argument of the previous line in the history. If you have parameters in between, then you can use `!:1` for the first argument, `!:2` forthe second argument, etc.

From bash(1):

> ## Event Designators
>
> An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the
>   history list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events are relative
>   to the current position in the history list.
>
> `!`      Start a history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
>   newline, carriage return, `=` or `(` (when the extglob shell option is
>   enabled using the shopt builtin).
>
> [..]
>
> ## Word Designators
>
> Word designators are used to select desired words from the event.
>   A `:` separates the event specification from the word designator. [..]
>
> [..]
>   *n* The *n*-th word.
>   `^`      The first argument.  That is, word 1.
>   `$`      The last word.  This is usually the last argument, but will
>   expand to the zeroth word if there is only one word in the line.

Comment: I think that "!:1" loses vs "$firstfewcharactersofnewdir+TAB" in most cases...

Comment: @Jasper I seldomly use `!:1`, but it is an option if you have a path with a non-unique prefix.

Comment: `!$` is shorter and easier to type on many keyboards. See also `<Alt-.>` or `<Alt-_>`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Nice one, I'll update the answer to use `!$` instead.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas What is the difference between Alt+. and Alt+_?

Comment: @bernard you can move forward and backward in the parameter list. See the manual page of bash.

Comment: Other than typing "mkdir", "cd", white space, and theFolderName, this answer requires typing only 2 more characters. That's how I evaluate the best answer

Answer (score 16):

These other lads are just making life complicated, here it is:

```
eval {mkdir,cd}\ FOLDER\;
```

Comment: I really wanted to make a directory called `'FOLDER && rm ../something'`. But `eval` won't let me :*( Tragically, may have to choose complicated in the battle of complicated vs [evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: @BroSlow, well then you'll have to find another OS, since having a slash in a filename has never been allowed! as for the other characters they work just fine if escaped.

Comment: @SeanD You're missing my point. Using `eval` with user input is generally a bad idea and `eval` will process `FOLDER && rm ../something` in place of `FOLDER` without complaint. Or for another variant, how about `"FOLDER && rm -r $HOME"`

Comment: @BroSlow This isn't using `eval` with user input, so it's fine. Don't cargo cult.

Comment: @MilesRout If you only ever use it for a directory called `FOLDER`, sure, this is fine. That's not the point, if you use it with variable input (which you almost certainly are going to), the results for weird directory names can at best cause unexpected results, at worst pose a security risk.

Comment: old af  I kjnow, but if that made onto any attack surface this guy was going to burn it all down eventually, one way or another. this is fine fine as a local convenience. or, would be if it had a couple p's